# code igniter :: send url as param?

Tags: codeigniter

I am creating an ajax function to edit some settings.

these must be handled via the url

(i.e)

the url would be http://example.com/setting1/setting2/setting3

This works fine but.
One of the settings is a url.

How could I pass this in this way?

Comment: You should consider switching the Ajax call to a POST request (instead of a GET request). This is simple to do in most AJAX toolkits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this might work

```
$url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245416/code-igniter-send-url-as-param';

$encoded = base64_encode($url);
//aHR0cDovL3N0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3cuY29tL3F1ZXN0aW9ucy80MjQ1NDE2L2NvZGUtaWduaXRlci1zZW5kLXVybC1hcy1wYXJhbQ==

// Make your URL
$my_url = "site.com/controller/method/params/params/" . $encoded;

// redirect or whatever

$encoded_url = $this->uri->segment(4); // (or wherever the URL is)

$url = base64_decode($encoded_url);
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245416/code-igniter-send-url-as-param
```

Comment: +1. This is the only way I know to do that. But of course it is better to switch to POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the URI Class: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

From index.php/user/search/name/joe/location/UK/gender/male

You can get:

```
[array]
(
    'name' => 'joe'
    'location'  => 'UK'
    'gender'    => 'male'
)
```

Using:

```
$array = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(3);
```

You can also find useful $this->uri->segment_array() .

Comment: I am aware of this.
But,

One of the params (lets say location is a website location) is a url you end up with
`
index.php/user/search/name/joe/location/http://stackoverflow.com/users/383759/hailwood/gender/male`

I am sure you can see the issue there...

Comment: Try with the segment_array(), you can ignore the first value if is something like /ajax/setting1/setting2. It will work.

Comment: That is not the issue. The issue is, the characters in the url are breaking it.