# URL encode incoming URL with CI

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, controller, urlencode

I have a controller that takes a URL as a parameter. The URL has forward slashes and a query string, it looks something like this:

`http://example.com/foo?bar=baz&bar2=baz2`

<s>The problem is, the URL comes in unencoded and there is no way I can change that.</s> *(Forgot to mention that I CAN actually encode the URL before hand, that certainly changes things)*

I want to encode the URL before it hits my controller and then I want to echo out this URL on the page.

Does codeigniter have any built in methods or what is the `.htaccess` rule I need to set to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

hacked around a little and figured it out:

What you do is encode the URL as base64

`base64_encode($uri)`;

and if you get a disallowed characters in URI message , go to `application/config/config.php` and set `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` to accept the problem characters. In my case I needed to enable `=` to my parameter.

Final config param looks like this:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-='; //added = sign to permit to enable base64 encode
```

on the controller end I simply have a `echo base64_decode($url);`

This way I can pass pretty much any string into the URL segment and it works.

The URL segment will be encoded with a series of numbers and letters translating to the string that has a URI encoded within it.

:)

( P.S. Happy Hanukkah & Marry xMAS)

---

Thanks to this question for assistance

[code igniter :: send url as param?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245416/code-igniter-send-url-as-param)